# How safe are money market accounts with online banks like CapitalOne?

Tags: savings, money-market

I received a promotional offer from CapitalOne where they are offering 1.00% interest rate for deposits above 10K. I wanted to know how safe is such investment with online banks vis-a-vis regular banks? Also - is their any downside to such investments? Thanks.

Comment: I've been using a "high interest" online savings accounts for about 15 years.  Never had any problems, although I have not used CapitalOne.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd call 1% interest an "investment" in any real sense - that's less than inflation.

Comment: I interpreted "online bank" as one that only exists online (no physical branch locations), like Ally bank.  Capital One has tons of physical locations.

Comment: Yes, I'd assume 1% is not a high rate and not an investment, but it is better than 0.02%, isn't it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanted to know how safe is such investment with online banks vis-a-vis regular banks?

As far as I know, neither money market accounts nor savings accounts have any investment risk (within reason) since both are [insured by the FDIC](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/053016/how-safe-are-money-market-accounts.asp). Note that this is not necessarily the case with money market *funds*.

> is their any downside to such investments?

Yes, there are [a few](http://finance.zacks.com/advantages-disadvantages-money-market-accounts-2170.html). I believe the two biggest ones  are:

1. High minimum balance
2. Limited transfers

Comment: Another downside is that 1% is not really 'high'.

Comment: It is compared to most savings accounts. I know discover's is around 1% though

Comment: Yes, but compared to other 'investments', it is poor (yes, therefore it is secure, but it is a potential downside of this _investment_ compared to others)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The first question OP asked was specifically savings and money market though

Comment: Thanks. I have some amount that is just lying around in the savings account without really generating any interest on it. So better to move it to such money market account where I stand to get very high (compared to savings rate) interest rate. I do understand its not really an investment, but I am not very sure about the type of investment I can do with this money and don't have any timeframe in mind as well. So my current criteria is to get higher returns with high liquidity and less risk :)

Comment: @V_Singh money market accounts are still investments, just lower returns and lower risk than many other investments. I think you'll be achieving your investment goals very nicely :)